# Behavior of boost::asio::io_service thread pool during uneven load

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have hard time finding out how exactly does thread pool built with `boost::asio::io_service` behave.

The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html) says:

> Multiple threads may call the `run()` function to set up a pool of
>   threads from which the io_service may execute handlers. **All threads
>   that are waiting in the pool are equivalent and the io_service may
>   choose any one of them to invoke a handler.**

I would imagine, that when threads executing `run()` are taking a handler to execute, they execute it, and then come back to wait for next handlers to execute. When executing a handler, a thread is not considered waiting, and hence no new handlers to execute are assigned to it. Is that correct? Or does `io_service` assign work to threads, without considering whether these are busy or not?

I am asking, because in one project that we are using ([OSRM](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend)), that uses `boost::asio::io_service` based thread pool to handle incoming HTTP requests, I noticed that long running request, **sometimes** block other, fast requests, even though more threads and cores are available.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the two possibilities you mentioned. Both will lead to blocking after a task is executed. Also consider that there are no priorities (or anything similar) assigned to tasks when pushed to the queue... how do you expect `io_service` to make any difference between tasks?

Comment: If thread is busy, and new work is assigned to it, it will be able to handle the new work item only after it finished processing whatever it was busy with. Hence the work item has to wait for processing, even though other threads in the pool are available. In the other possibility, tasks are assigned only to non-busy threads, and hence if there are any available threads, the work item processing starts immediately.

Comment: OK, now I see the issue. Actually I don't believe that. I often used `io_service` for thread pools (not the best practice, I know), and never noticed this. You could easily create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you demonstrate the problem with simple sleep functions, and then we can discuss based on evidence. Guessing what a library does is futile.

Answer (score 1):

> When executing a handler, a thread is not considered waiting, and hence no new handlers to execute are assigned to it. Is that correct?

Yes. It's a pull model queue.

A notable "apparent" exception is when strands are used: handlers wrapped on a on a strand do synchronize with other handlers running on that same strand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you maybe have a reference to a documentation or code, which would show that?

Comment: It's all over. The fact that it doesn't say that there's task-to-thread affinity is enough. I mean, really. You don't ask me to quote the docs where it says that it doesn't kill puppies¹ (¹ with the exception of [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior))

Comment: This might help http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html